# difference between "dependency information" and "dependencies" in the auto-generated site

Tags: maven

I am new to Maven, built a project from the getting started archetype, and typed maven site. Then I am able to view a page called "dependency information" where fields like "Groovy Grape" and "Apache Ant" appear, and a page called "dependencies" where the only dependency listed in the pom appears ( junit ).
So what are all those fields from the first page ?

Answer (score 0):

`Dependency information` describes how you can add this file as dependency to your own project. In case of Maven: copy the `<dependency/>` entry and put it in your `pom.xml` between the `<dependencies></dependencies>` tags
`Dependency` describes all the dependencies used by this project. If you were using an old-fashion build-tool, you need to add all this files to the classpath manually, otherwise you might end up with a ClassNotFoundException. However, Maven can do this for you, so no extra actions required.